# Making HTML from String

Tags: javascript, html

This is my **content**:

```
var config = {
    first: {
        value: 'example', type: 'text', label: 'Name'
    },
    second: {
        value: 'some', type: 'text', label: 'Family' }
};
```

Any idea for make 2 input according to **first** and **second** ?

i need to make this field with this method:

```
document.createElement('input'); //eg
```

Making two input html field using javascript, according to my config.

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to do and what you've tried so far to achieve it.

Comment: _"Any idea..."_ - Sure. And it wouldn't be that complicated. Might be fun to implement. Just give it a try.

Comment: Just input, eg: <input type="text" value="name">

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: My question is very simple ! eg: document.createElement()......

Comment: If it is very simple, then you shouldn't have any issues attempting it on your own first.  We are not here to write code for you.  We are here to help you learn why your attempts are not working.  Without an attempt, we have no idea what issues you are having doing it yourself.

Comment: Look. making two input html field using javascript, according to my config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to interate over all object properties and create a label & input for each, and then append it to the DOM. Here's some example code:

```
var config = {
    first: {
        value: 'example', type: 'text', label: 'Name'
    },
    second: {
        value: 'some', type: 'text', label: 'Family' }
};

Object.keys(config).forEach(key => {
var container = document.getElementById("input-boxes");

var inputEl = document.createElement("input");
var label = document.createElement("LABEL");
label.innerHTML = config[key].label;

inputEl.type = config[key].type;
inputEl.value = config[key].value;

container.appendChild(label); // put label into the DOM
container.appendChild(inputEl); // put it into the DOM
});
```

Here's how this example works in reality:

https://jsfiddle.net/ea65f4sq/3/

Comment: You quickly understood what I said, thank you very much . It was really great.

Comment: @Pedroxam We all understood your "question", but SO is not a "give me the solution because I have better things to do" place.

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/themustafaomar/pen/YzXmqMY?editors=1011

```
var config = {
  first: {
    value: "example",
    type: "text",
    label: "Name"
  },
  second: {
    value: "some",
    type: "text",
    label: "Family"
  }
};

Object.keys(config).forEach((key) => {
  var container = document.createElement("div");
  var field = document.createElement("input");
  var label = document.createElement("label");

  label.textContent = config[key].label;

  field.value = config[key].value;
  field.setAttribute("type", config[key].type);
  container.appendChild(label);

  container.appendChild(field);
  document.body.appendChild(container);
});
```